# Can you solve this cryptic crossword clue?

Tags: cryptic-clues

I'm one word off finishing a cryptic crossword and I'm stuck. Can you solve:

> 24a. Run away with bag, coming back for the proverbially untouchable (9)

I have the following letters - hidden for those who wish to start from scratch.

> B_R_E_O_E

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can solve:

> Run away with (ELOPE) + bag (GRAB), coming back = BARGEPOLE, something you proverbially wouldn't touch something untouchable with.